# Best / most cross browser stable way to add vertical spacing between objects in an html newsletter?

Tags: html, html-table, newsletter

What is the best / most cross browser stable way to add vertical spacing between objects in an html newsletter ?

At the moment im adding in a row like this `<tr height="30" width="100%"></tr>` As you cant really use margin / padding on objects as it breaks in some versions of outlook.

Is this the best way or is there a better / more cross browser stable way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
<td height="20" width="100%" style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
```

The `nbsp;` is for older versions of Outlooks that collapse empty `td`s. Similarly the line-height and font-size are for Outlooks that have a minimum height. For example, Outlook 2016 has a minimum height of 17 pixels. Obviously, it would be fine to not include line height for spacers of 20, but I keep them in there just in case I switch it to 5 later on.

The height, font-size, line-height should all be the same number.

Comment: Thanks @Taylor i could actually see the code you inputted, could you update the answer ? I guess what you wrote was `<tr height="30" width="100%">nbsp;</tr>` - is that correct ?

Comment: @sam Fixed it. I was on my phone and the spaces kept turning into `.`s. >.<